# Append new line to string

Tags: ios, nsstring

Hi I'm generating a string which consists of text entries from text fields.

```
NSString * lines = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,%@,%@,%@,%@", [self.crabText text], [self.trawlText text], [self.trapText text], [self.vesselText text], [self.lengthText text]];
```

I generate the above string when the user selects a "Generate CSV" UIButton which follows by an IBAction. However, I then want to clear the text fields and append the new populated entries on top of the previous ones. However, only the current text field entries will be populated due to the function always creating a new instance of the "lines" string.

```
lines = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@\n", lines];
```

I have this working by putting all new strings into an array but was wondering if it were possible to just use the same string. 
An example would be "1,1,1,1,1" "new  line" "2,2,2,2,2".

Comment: Just add the `\n` to the end of the first string format.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't do this:

```
NSString * lines = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,%@,%@,%@,%@", [self.crabText text], [self.trawlText text], [self.trapText text], [self.vesselText text], [self.lengthText text]];
```

Do this:

```
NSArray *fields = @[[self.crabText text],
                   [self.trawlText text],
                   [self.trapText text],
                   [self.vesselText text],
                   [self.lengthText text]];
NSString *line = [fields componentsJoinedByString:@","];
```

Then, to join two lines together:

```
NSArray *lines = @[lineOne, lineTwo];
NSString *linesString = [lines componentsJoinedByString:@"\n"];
```

Comment: +1 nice approach and it's also less error prone in case the fields increase in quantity.

Comment: The only thing is how would I retrieve "lineOne, and lineTwo"?

Comment: Don't fix on details such variable names. Each line will be produced as `line` is in the example.

Comment: @user2402616 basically you should create an array of lines however you want, and then join them together at the end.

Comment: Yes but wouldn't this require creating a new string lineOne,lineTwo...lineN every time the user adds a csv?

Comment: You could create the `lines` variable like this: `NSArray *lines = [[NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:@"path/to/file.csv"] componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];`

Comment: Alternatively you could use NSFileHandle and just write to the file directly... there are a million approaches, try them all and then decide which one you prefer. ;)

Comment: I'm writing the .csv to the documents directory. Is there any way to append my lines string by a new line to the file? If so, this would be the most efficient way to solve my problem without using arrays or nsmutable strings. Thanks!

Comment: I solved it by using 
    NSArray *fields = @[[self.crabText text],
                        [self.trawlText text],
                        [self.trapText text],
                        [self.vesselText text],
                        [self.lengthText text]];
    NSString *lines = [fields componentsJoinedByString:@","];
    [self.list addObject:lines];
    
    NSMutableString *test = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];

    for (int i = 0; i<self.list.count; i++) {
        [test appendFormat:@"\n%@",[self.list objectAtIndex:i]];
    }

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you could use an `NSMutableString` and `appendString` to append to it each time.